# How can I exclude some packages (within a JAR) from a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I am depending on a library in my Maven project and I find that the library's JAR contains some packages which cause my application to fail.  I believe the library should still work if I can somehow exclude these packages, but I would like to do this via Maven, rather than by hacking the JAR file myself.  Is there a way to do this with Maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the `maven-shade-plugin`. An example is shown in the official [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
              <includes>
                <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                <include>org/junit/**</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```